# Accesing a file outside my applicadtion data folder

Tags: android

Where should I copy a file (in my case it is a sqlite database) to let my application copy it to its data folder? I have tried some locations with no luck. It seems I don't have enough permissions.

Comment: You MUST read the Android developer documentation on [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). All the information you require is contained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want to use sqlite database on your application? If so, just use SQL helper class can do create and maintain job. If not, you can use assets (it is a folder in your project) to store it, and then copy it to SD card, if you can't copy it with permission issue, you can add its permission - `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

You can copy it to Android/data/your folder/, this is private data, and will delete when your app is uninstalled. For another way, you can copy it to data/your folder/ too. Or create any folder you like on SD card, then copy it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It Depends on how big your database is. if your application is doing too much back and forth database operations like loading the data or writing datas back in database than you should better copy your database file anywhere(better to put in application package folder) in SD card. hope **[this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)** will help you.

and for the file copying operation you need **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** in your manifest file.